# Comment reply works on local but not production

Tags: php, wordpress

So I can reply to comments on local but it doesn't work on live. I can reply via the admin panel but when I click reply on a comment on a single page, it doesn't work.

I checked the code and it seems like the href of the reply button is rendered differently.

This is how it looks on localhost

```
<a rel="nofollow" class="comment-reply-link" href="http://localhost:8888/foobar/?replytocom=1285#respond" data-commentid="1285" data-postid="7086" data-belowelement="comment-1285" data-respondelement="respond" data-replyto="Reply to foobar" aria-label="Reply to arsd">Reply</a>
```

This is how it looks on production

```
<a rel="nofollow" class="comment-reply-link" href="#comment-1285" data-commentid="1285" data-postid="7086" data-belowelement="comment-1285" data-respondelement="respond" data-replyto="Reply to Alex Kwa" aria-label="Reply to foobar">Reply</a>
```

I'm thinking it could be either a plugin, permalink or htaccess issue.

- I don't have any plugins that touches the comments.
- My permalink is custom but where possible I would like not to change it due to SEO impact.
- My htaccess looks like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE] 

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

SetEnv MAGICK_THREAD_LIMIT 1
```

Any help will be much appreiciated.

Comment: How do you generate the url in the comment reply link? can you state the out in your question?

Comment: I believe that it's generated by the wp-includes/comment-template.php
I have not made any changes to the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know I stated that it doesn't seem like a plugin issue, but I've found the problem is actually with a plugin, Yoast SEO.
A similar issue can be found [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/cant-reply-to-comments-after-yoast-update/).

I've fixed it by disabling the specific function that replaces `replytocom` to `comment` by including this into my function.php

`add_filter( 'wpseo_remove_reply_to_com', '__return_false' );`

Note that this does not solve the issue, but according to Yoast SEO, it's a problem with themes that scroll you to the comment input form upon a reply so they won't be fixing it on their end.